# How to correctly add up and compare all possible 3x3 grids in 2D array?

Tags: arrays, grid

I could use some help adding up all possible 3x3 grids inside my 2D array.
For example, consider the following grid,

1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 1 2 3

How could I add up all possible 3x3 grids starting with the top leftmost cell

1 2 3
7 8 9
1 2 3

Then move to the next cell to the right

2 3 4
8 9 1
2 3 4

Finally moving down when I need to

7 8 9
1 2 3
7 8 9

Here is what I have so far, but I cannot get it to work.

```
while( (n+2) < row)
{
  temp = 0;

for (int i = n; i < (n+3) ; i++)
  for (int j = n; j < (n+3); j++)
    temp += gridArr[i][j];

  if ( n == 0 )
  {
    sum = temp;
    final = temp;
  }
  if ( temp < sum )
    final = temp;

n++;
}
cout << sum << endl;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have to compare the 3x3 grids and output the one with the least value.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to identify the 3 x 3 grids by specifying their upper, left corner. Using this position as a base point, move through the larger grid and sum each 3 x 3 sub grid. Store the smallest sum and compare with each grid. Using this approach you would check the 3 x 3 grids based at 0 - 2 columns and 0 - 1 rows.

Sample code in C#:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int gridSum;
        int minGridSum = int.MaxValue;           
        int[,] gridArr = new int[,]{
            {1,2,3,4,5,6},
            {7,8,9,1,2,3},
            {1,2,3,4,5,6},
            {7,8,9,1,2,3}
        };

        //start from first and second row
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            //start from first 4 columns
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
            {
                gridSum = GetGridSum(i, j, gridArr);
                Console.WriteLine("Sum of grid " + (i * 4 + j) + ": " + gridSum);
                if (gridSum < minGridSum) minGridSum = gridSum;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Minimum grid sum: " + minGridSum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //Find the sum of a single 3 x 3 grid    
    static int GetGridSum(int rowStart, int colStart, int[,] gridArr)
    {
        int gridSum = 0;
        for (int i = rowStart; i <= (rowStart + 2); i++)
        {
            for (int j = colStart; j <= (colStart + 2); j++)
            {
                gridSum += gridArr[i,j];
            }
        }
        return gridSum;
    }
```

Output:

```
Sum of grid located at [0,0]: 36
Sum of grid located at [0,1]: 36
Sum of grid located at [0,2]: 36
Sum of grid located at [0,3]: 36
Sum of grid located at [1,0]: 54
Sum of grid located at [1,1]: 45
Sum of grid located at [1,2]: 36
Sum of grid located at [1,3]: 27
Minimum grid sum: 27
```